# Adding QUERY_TAG to task queries

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For monitoring & logging purposes - we have several tasks that we wish to add QUERY_TAG to each of them.

AFAIK - QUERY_TAG is only working at the session-level - is there any way to add QUERY_TAG to the snowflake tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Session parameters can be set for Tasks within the CREATE TASK statement, and the QUERY_TAG is no exception.

An example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK_TEST_QUERY_TAG
    WAREHOUSE = MY_WH
    SCHEDULE = '1 MINUTE'
    QUERY_TAG = 'My Test Query Tag'
AS
[...]    
;
```

Check the CREATE TASK syntax:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TASK [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name>
  WAREHOUSE = <string>
  [ SCHEDULE = '{ <num> MINUTE | USING CRON <expr> <time_zone> }' ]
  [ <session_parameter> = <value> [ , <session_parameter> = <value> ... ] ]
  [ USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = <num> ]
  [ COPY GRANTS ]
  [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
  [ AFTER <string> ]
[ WHEN <boolean_expr> ]
AS
  <sql>
```

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#syntax

Comment: `QUERY_TAG` is not present in the doc's page you link too.. nor in the syntax you present for `CREATE TASK`

Comment: After testing agree that QUERY_TAG is accepted and can be seen in the command `SELECT GET_DDL('task','<task_name>');`

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim QUERY_TAG is one of the optional session parameters in the syntax [ <session_parameter> = <value> [ , <session_parameter> = <value> ... ] ]

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake tasks are comprised of a single command- so alter session + your command would exceed that.

You could create a simple stored procedure that would set the query tab and run your command.  Then, have your task call that.